# How to insert JSON string in html input tag while binding via loadsh.js

Tags: javascript, html, json

How to insert a JSON string in HTML input tag while binding via loadsh.js?

I'm using loadash lib to bind data in HTML

```
<input value="${ mydata.value }" width="200px" />
```

here I have to bind the JSON string data inside the dom element. It evaluates as below

```
<input value="{"
              value1":"2","v2":"v3"}" width="200px" />
```

now value i have is only "{". So anyway to get the value with full JSON.

And I have tried JSON.stringify() which is give the same result I mentioned above.

```
<input value="${ JSON.stringify(mydata.value) }" width="200px" />
```

In some scenario, I had a problem with a single quote.

```
<input value='{"name":"K'naan"}' />
```

it will evaluate as

```
value='{"name":"K'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use simple `'` instead of `"`

So your code should be

```
<input value='${ mydata.value }' width="200px" />
```

and this will generate the below element which is valid.

```
<input value='{"value1":"2","v2":"v3"}' width="200px" />
```

Single quote should be used as the outside of your JSON so the inside can use double quotes as per JSON specifications.

Comment: In some scenario, I had a problem with single quote its self like what is my JSON has a value with a single quote?